# Spring Integration: Extending AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer

Tags: spring, ftp, integration, sftp

I have a working sftp inbound channel adapter defined in the config xml (apparently defining this via annotations is not fully functional in Spring as yet).

What I would like to do is override the synchronizeToLocalDirectory method so that it can be manually activated with the help of JMX.

Instantiating the class with @Component happens, however the synchronizeToLocalDirectory in my class never gets called because it is separate to the actually bean invoked by Spring though the config xml.

Is there a way to pair the two so that my synchronizeToLocalDirectory method is called every time?

My Inbound File Synchronizer :

```
@Component
@ManagedResource(objectName = "bean:name=InboundFileProcessor", description = "Synchronizes to the Local Directory",
log = true, logFile = "jmx.log", currencyTimeLimit = 15, persistPolicy = "OnUpdate", persistPeriod = 200,
persistLocation = "Spring", persistName = "FTP")
public class MyFtpInboundFileSynchronizer extends AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer<LsEntry> {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyFtpInboundFileSynchronizer.class);
@Inject
private MultiMarkupFilter multiMarkupFilter;

@Inject
public MyFtpInboundFileSynchronizer(SessionFactory<LsEntry> ftpSessionFactory) {
    super(ftpSessionFactory);
    setRemoteDirectory(((FtpSessionFactory) ftpSessionFactory).getFtpSessionProperties().getRemoteDirectory());
    setFilter(multiMarkupFilter);

}

public void init() {

}

@Override
protected boolean isFile(LsEntry lsEntry) {
    if (lsEntry != null && !lsEntry.getAttrs().isDir()
            && !lsEntry.getFilename().equals(".")
            && !lsEntry.getFilename().equals("..")) {
        logger.debug("Downloading file" + lsEntry.getFilename());
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
protected String getFilename(LsEntry file) {
    return (file != null ? file.getFilename() : null);
}

@Override
public void synchronizeToLocalDirectory(File localDirectory) {
    logger.debug("Starting synchronizeToLocalDirectory");
    super.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(localDirectory);
    logger.debug("Ending synchronizeToLocalDirectory");
}

@ManagedOperation(description = "synchronize To Local Directory")
@ManagedOperationParameters({ @ManagedOperationParameter(name = "localDirectory", description = "The Local Directory") })
public void synchronizeToLocalDirectory(String localDirectory) {
    File localDirFile = new File(localDirectory);
    if (localDirFile.exists() && localDirFile.isDirectory()) {
        synchronizeToLocalDirectory(new File(localDirectory));
    }
  }
}
```

int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter definition :

```
    <int:annotation-config/>

<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
    channel="ftpChannel" session-factory="${sessionFactory}"
    auto-create-local-directory="${autoCreateLocalDirectory}"
    delete-remote-files="${deleteRemoteFiles}" filter="${filter}"
    remote-directory="${remoteDirectory}"
    remote-file-separator="${remoteFileSeparator}"
    local-directory="${localDirectory}">
   <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="-1"
    fixed-rate="${ftpPollInterval}" id="poller" error-channel="errorChannel" >
   </int:poller>
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="ftpChannel"/>
<int:channel id="errorChannel"/>
```